# Understanding this case of polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I have two classes, `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` that are derived from the same `Base` class. Both classes hold pointers to an object each, which is of one of two data types, `TypeA` and `TypeB`, respectively. Those data types are derived from the same basic type `BaseType`.

In the `Base` class, I have an (abstract) getter for those pointers. That getter is overridden in the each of the derived classes and specified such that they should return the derived data types.

In the `main` function, I define a vector that holds pointers to objects of both derived classes. But when I iterate over that vector, I only get `BaseType` pointers instead of the expected `TypeA`/`TypeB` pointers.

The following MWE illustrates that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BaseType {};
class TypeA : public BaseType {};
class TypeB : public BaseType {};

class Base {
public:
  virtual BaseType* GetObject() = 0;
};

class DerivedA: public Base {
public:
  TypeA* object = new TypeA();
  TypeA* GetObject() override {
    cout << "i'm comming from DerivedA" << endl;
    return object;
  }
};

class DerivedB: public Base {
public:
  TypeB* object = new TypeB();
  TypeB* GetObject() override {
    cout << "i'm comming from DerivedB" << endl;
    return object;
  }
};


int main() {
  vector<Base*> vec = {new DerivedA(), new DerivedB()};
  for (auto* item : vec){
    auto* obj_ptr = item->GetObject();
    cout << "I have an object of type " << typeid(obj_ptr).name() << endl;
  }
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
i'm comming from DerivedA
I have an object of type P8BaseType
i'm comming from DerivedB
I have an object of type P8BaseType
```

Now, I have two questions the answers to which I hope to help me to understand how polymorphism in C++ works:

1. Why does the call to the `GetObject()` for each vector item clearly lands in the correct override, but does not return `TypeA*` or `TypeB*`, respectively, but a pointer to a `BaseType` instead?
2. How would I need to alter the code to get pointers to types `TypeA` and `TypeB`, respectively?

Comment: 1) You need to learn about `virtual` functions, as dynamic polymorphism doesn't exist without it. --  *After a bit of searching and trial and error* -- 2) C++ cannot be learned by trial and error.  C++ requires reading and using peer-reviewed materials such as good books and approved websites.

Comment: Add the print functionality to the classes themself: https://godbolt.org/z/cvh49Esjj

Comment: @mch damn, my "breakdown" was broken down too much. In my real problem (which involves lists of wrappers for `wxMenu` and `wxMenuItem`), I don't just want to print something, but I want to return the content to process it further. I actually tried your way before but apparently, a virtual method cannot be overridden by methods that return different Types.

Comment: @Lupino So the processing also needs to be in virtual methods. That is the way you do the "same thing" for different kinds of data. Or maybe you need a function that returns a string representation of the data in order to process the string further. It is hard to say without knowing the actual problem.

Comment: Create function objects that have members, state, etc.   The members would serve as the parameters and return type(s).   Then overload the call operator, `operator()`.  Then it is `operator()` that is called in a loop for each object.  Basically you're moving the parameters from the call site to within the function object.

Comment: Aside from virtual functions (which is the way to go here), there's also a ````std::variant```` type (which goes togehter with ````std::visit````). But don't put the cart before the horse.

Comment: A starting point may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I spent the most part of the past two weeks reading through [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-plus-plus/?ref=shm).  Would you consider this an "approved" resource for learning?

Comment: @Lupino: I heard mixed opionions about geeksforgeeks, but no first hand experience. I found learncpp.com to be really helpfull. It starts at the very beginning, so you might skip a few chapters, though.

Comment: G4G? In two words, stay away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your sample.

First, `BaseType` is not polymorphic so `typeid` will not use RTTI. Adding a virtual function solves this.

```
class BaseType {
public:
    virtual ~BaseType() = default;
};
```

Second, `typeid` inspects the dynamic type of its operand if possible, but does not special-case pointers. `obj_ptr` itself is unequivocally of type `BaseType *`, even if it points to a derived object. `*obj_ptr`, on the other hand, is a `BaseType &` which `typeid(*obj_ptr)` will gladly query for its dynamic type.

[See the resulting code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/91PYhWhM7)

Comment: I don't quite understand why declaring a virtual destructor is working in this case. Is there some rule that states that there has to be at least one method that is set to be "virtual"  in the declaration part so that the compiler knows that it is meant to be a polymorphic class? And regarding the second issue: `*` in front of a pointer returns the "real" object that is pointed to; so I don't pass the pointer to `typeid` but the actual object, correct? Or a copy of that object?

Comment: @Lupino that's precisely the rule, yes: a class needs at least one virtual function to become polymorphic, which is to say opt-in to RTTI. Your understanding about `*` is correct as well: the actual object is passed by reference (that's the point of references in the first place, to have a "thing" to pass around to refer to an object without making pointers ambiguous).

Comment: Oh, now i see: I need to make the base *Type* virtual as well, not just the Base *class* that uses this type. This was the thing I was missing. Thanks.